# Conditional GAN - shuffle/split two datasets identically

Tags: dataset, pytorch, dcgan

I'm trying to use train a DCGAN to colorize some images. When doing so, I condition my GAN on grayscale versions of the images. I then want to train my GAN/discriminator first with a batch of real images, and then with a batch of fake images. Every so often, I want to compare the colorized, grayscale and ground truth version of the images. I therefore need the batches of the real/gray images to be split the same way. I use pytorch. Looking at the code I've included, these should give the same batches. However, they don't.

I have tried without worker_init_fn. I have also tried different random function calls and passed them to worker_init_fn with no avail.

```
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=workers, worker_init_fn = random.seed(seed))

dataloader_gray = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset_gray, batch_size=batch_size,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=workers, worker_init_fn = random.seed(seed))

for i, (data, data_gray) in enumerate(zip(dataloader, dataloader_gray)):
    doStuff()
```

Comment: You are loading the colored images and gray images in separate dataloaders, how do you ensure that they are paired correctly?

Comment: Haran perhaps I phrased my question poorly. My question is how to pair the images correctly in the batches. By splitting the batches using the same RNG/seed, the images should be paired correctly. However, I can't get it right..

Comment: Try using `torch.manual_seed()` instead. Also have you checked what the first images the loader loads? 

Do the color and gray correspond to each other?
In a different run, do the loaders load the same order of images?

Comment: I tried worker_init_fn = torch.manual_seed. Doesn't change anything. The results are shown here https://imgur.com/a/uCSDvmB. The gray should just be the gray versions of the images, not completely different.

Comment: `torch.manual_seed(<some number>)` should be set at the beginning of your script.

Comment: Setting torch.manual_seed(12) at the beginning of my script does not solve the problem sadly.

Comment: Do you get the same image results on multiple runs?

Comment: I would recommend creating a new class that inherits dataset that loads both images sequentially. This would be a more robust solution compared to playing with the seed values.

Comment: Yes. If I use torch.manual_seed(12) I get the the image results. If I remove manual seed, I don't. Since we are iterating over two dataloaders, I think they both change the RNG state which gives us different gray/color images.

Answer (score 0):

As [Haran Rajkumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6523063/haran-rajkumar) pointed in the comments, much better solution would involve concatenating both datasets beforehand and applying `torch.utils.DataLoader` after that (provided both `torch.utils.Dataset` objects contain images in the exact same order at the beginning).

Notice that one doesn't have to create separate class to perform this operation, `torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset` provides this functionality out of the box.

Not sure about your exact code, but this should be enough (or at least enough to get you in the right direction):

```
import torch

dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset(dataset, dataset_gray),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True,
    num_workers=workers
)

for i, (data, data_gray) in enumerate(dataloader):
    doStuff()
```

As you can see it is much more readable and easier to use.

Comment: Thank you. I took @HaranRajkumar's advice and created a new class. It works!

Comment: IMO this approach is a little shorter and readable, but glad it worked out for you.